# Can not remove user from db_owner-group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

***TL;DR - Users automatically get added to db_owner group when created by script for some reason. But I can't remove them with a script.***

So I have made a script to add new Windows-users to my database but for some reason they automatically get added to the db_owner group by default. The owner on the server is 'sa' so there is an owner set already on the server.

[image]

[image]

This is what happens when I add a new user with the following script:

```
CREATE LOGIN [Windows\user1] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO

USE [dbName]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM [sys].[database_principals] WHERE [name] = N'Windows\user1')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [Windows\user1] FOR LOGIN [Windows\user1]
END
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember 'Admin', 'Windows\user1'
GO
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'Windows\user1'
GO
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'Windows\user1'
GO
```

But when I run the following code it says "1 row affected". But the user is still in the db_owner group.

```
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] DROP MEMBER [Windows\user1]
```

*The only way I can remove it right now is using the UI in SSMS to go to the properties of the user and un-check it. What are some ways to fix either of the issues?*

**Apparently this wasn't correct. They don't even get removed this way...**

Update(1):
I've managed to narrow it down to the fact that it does seem to have something to do with the custom role "Admin" - when a user is added to this role it automatically gets added to db_owner when running the following script.

```
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember 'Admin', 'Windows\user1'
```

Still haven't managed to figure out why.

Comment: Side note: `sp_addrolemember` is planned to be removed from SQL Server, you should not be using it any more. Use `ALTER ROLE` and `ADD` the `MEMBER`.

Comment: @Larnu good to know, this is a temporary solution that's only going to be in use for the next... 3-6 months. After that I don't have to add users this way anymore.

Comment: `ALTER ROLE` should not give back a `1 row(s) affected` statement; if you are getting that it sounds like you have some database triggers doing *something*.

Comment: Is the Admin role a member of db_owner?

Comment: @DanGuzman - no. I have 2 separate databases with 'sa' owner on both. But this "db_owner" only happens in 1 of them...

Comment: @Larnu where can I find triggers that could have to do with this? SELECT * FROM sys.server_triggers returned 0 results.

Comment: It'll be a database trigger, not a server trigger. `USER`s and `ROLE`s are database objects.

Comment: @Larnu nothing relevant in sys.triggers either from what I could find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prediction: if you run the following query, then the result will be 1:

```sql
select   count(*)
from     sys.database_role_members   rm
join     sys.database_principals     rp   on rp.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id
join     sys.database_principals     mp   on mp.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
where    rp.name = 'db_owner'
         and mp.name = 'Admin';
```

If that is the case (and I am confident that it is), then the `Admin` role is a member of the `db_owner` role. So all members of `admin` are members of `db_owner`.

Then `user1` is given membership in the `admin` role. We now form a syllogism:

All `admins` are `db_owners`.
`user1` is an `admin`.
Therefore `user1` is a `db_owner`.

Attempting to remove `user1` from the `db_owner` role has no effect, because they are not a direct member of the `db_owner` role. They are a member of the `admin` role, which in turn is a member of the `db_owner` role.

If you want to remove their `db_owner` membership, you must do so by removing them from the `admin` role.

Comment: Is there any way to make "Admin" not part of the db_owner group?

Comment: `alter role db_owner drop member [admin]`. But you probably don't want to do that, someone surely created that role for some reason. If you can verify that the admin group is actually no longer needed, then yeah, clean it up.

Comment: Good point, but yes. You were correct. It did return 1. I have no idea why they built it like this. But I will work around it and try to remove the group slowly but surely.